# High-side load switch that is on by default

Tags: power-supply, switches

I need to control a 5V load from a 3.3V microprocessor I/O pin, but the load needs to be on if the pin is not initialized as an output or if the microprocessor is powered down. The pin cannot tolerate 5V applied externally.

I think this circuit will do it, where one of the N-channel MOSFETs serves as an inverter, but it seems more complicated than necessary. Can it be done with only 2 MOSFETs?
[image]

Comment: Remove most left transistor, its 50k connect to 3v3 supply (not 5v) and the low side of this 50k connect to mcu.

Comment: I don't entirely understand your proposal, but if the MPU is powered down there is no 3.3V supply. In that case the load still needs to be powered on.

Comment: See my answer below

Comment: Probably something involving a JFET or depletion-mode MOSFET would work, but I don't have the energy to work it all out right now.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to use the normally closed contact of a relay.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fIqIlG.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Otherwise, you do need to use 3 MOSFETs.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5qYSf.png)</sup>

Comment: A relay! That's kind of old-fashioned (and slow), but I think it can be modernized using an opto-isolator or solid-state relay thusly to get the normally-on behavior:
[schematic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AeS3z.png)
Only one MOSFET plus the opto-isolator. Does that look ok?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible using two MOSFETs only, but with some drawbacks:

- The value of the pulldown resistor R1 must be low compared to the pullup resistor R4 to provide sufficient low level at the gate of M2. This 1 mA load on the MCU port is not really elegant.
- The turn off time of M2 is long, so the circuit should not be used for higher frequencies.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZWX6J.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: A clever idea! And a 1mA load on the MCU port isn't as bad as having it drive the LED in an optocoupler.

Comment: @LenShustek Do you want to minimize board space or component cost?

Comment: I suppose I'm trying to minimize component count. --partly out of a desire for "elegance", and partly because at the moment I'm hand-fabricating the boards this circuit is on. Eventually I'll have JLCPCB make them, so using only components in their library is also of value.

Comment: @LenShustek Well, there are these little SOT-23-6 or smaller devices containing two transistors and 4 base resistors. I think there is one, that solves this problem at once. An alternative is a single non inverting HCT-CMOS buffer.

Comment: I'm trying to implement your clever 2-FET design, but I have a puzzle that must mean I'm doing something stupid. Look at this static test:
[schematic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CxpIO.png) When I build it I do get V_LOAD = Vsupply = 5V, and G1=2.5V. The CircuitLab DC Solver says I should get S1=309.6 mV and G2=309.8 mV, which makes sense. But what I measure is S1=1.6V and G2=4.2V. Any clue what's going on??

Comment: @LenShustek If you have 1.6 V across R1 there is a current of 0.485 mA through R1. The only path to the supply is through R4, but with R4 = 50 kohm this is impossible. Do you feed R1 from somewhere else? If yes, these voltages are possible.

Comment: It was a fabrication error! I gave JLCPCB the wrong part code for R1, and they populated it with a 100K resistor without noticing that it differed from the specified value of 3.3K. I replaced it, and it seems to be working. Thanks for your help and sorry for the false alarm.

Answer (score 0):

You can just remove the first transistor in your schematic. Since the M1 is biased from small voltage (3v3) use R1=22k rather.
There is no way the MCU pin will be stressed with 5V, btw.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvSbTT.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: The problem is that when the MCU is off, there is no source of 3.3V to keep M1 turned on. I suppose I could use a voltage divider from the 5V supply...

Comment: U can also place a zener diode to a pin but if 5V rail is stabillised use divider.

Comment: Another option is to use as M1 a BJT so you can be sure with 22k/2k2 in base  the voltage on MCU pin do not go higher than approx 1V.

Comment: An NPN BJT as M1 is also a good idea, although because it changes the sense of the MCU output (low now turns off the load) it makes the software incompatible for existing boards. But that's my problem...